# General solution to wave equation using traveling waves

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

In Stein and Shakarachi's *Fourier Analysis*, they prove the general solution to the $1$D wave equation. There is one step I cannot follow.

Let $u(x,t)$ be a solution to $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$. Then define $\xi = x+t$ and $\eta = x-t$ and set $v(\xi, \eta) = u(x,t)$. They then claim that this implies $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \xi \partial \eta} v(\xi, \eta) = 0$. I can sort of see how this works out, since there are two derivatives in $x$ and in $t$, with a minus sign so it turns into the wave equation for $u$, but I don't see the precise steps. Particularly, I'm trying to plug in $v(\xi, \eta)$ into the wave equation for $u(x,t)$ and am having trouble dealing with $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} v(x+t, x-t)$ and the other similar terms. How does one evaluate this? Is there is nicer was to see the relation for $v$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $\frac{\eta + \xi}{2} = x$ and $\frac{\xi- \eta}{2} = t$. Then by the chain rule,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial v}{\partial{\eta}} &= \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial \eta} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\frac{\partial t}{\partial \eta}\\
&= \frac{1}{2}(u_x - u_t).
\end{align*}
Taking one more derivative, we have
\begin{align*} 
\frac{\partial v}{\partial \xi \partial\eta} &= \frac{\partial u_x}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial \xi} +  \frac{\partial u_x}{\partial t}\frac{\partial t}{\partial \xi} -\frac{\partial u_t}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial \xi} -  \frac{\partial u_{t}}{\partial t}\frac{\partial t}{\partial \xi} \\
&= \frac{1}{4}(u_{xx} + u_{xt} - u_{tx} - u_{tt})
\end{align*}
The mixed partials are equal, so $u_{xt} = u_{tx}$. Also, $u_{xx} = u_{tt}$ since we assumed that $u$ solves the wave equation. Thus, it follows that
$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial \xi \partial\eta} = 0.$$

Comment: Just to be completely clear, the first line comes from $dv = du = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}dt$, right?

Comment: If you mean $\frac{\partial v}{\partial \eta} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial \eta}$, then yes.